# forEach zero pads a string, but map does not

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm working on some tools for crypto, and I was trying to use map to reduce some characters into a string. One function works, the other doesn't, but I have no idea why the second function does not 0 pad the string?

```js
// returns '0102'
export const bufferToHex = (buffer: Buffer): string => {
  const bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer)
  const hex = []
  bytes.forEach(byte => hex.push(byte.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')))
  return hex.join('')
}

// returns '12'
export const bufferToHex = (buffer: Buffer): string => {
  const bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer)
  return bytes
    .map((byte) => byte.toString(16).padStart(2, '0'))
    .join('')
}
```

And calling with:

```js
bufferToHex(Buffer.from([1, 2])
```

How is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`TypedArray.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/map) returns a new `TypedArray`, not an `Array`. The strings returned by your callback are being implicitly cast back to numbers when they're assigned to indices of the new `Uint8Array` created by the `.map()` method.

If you prefer to use `.map()` I would suggest the following:

```
export const bufferToHex = (buffer: Buffer): string => {
  return Array.prototype.map.call(
    buffer,
    (byte) => byte.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')
  ).join('')
}
```

The declaration of `bytes` is unnecessary since [`Buffer`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer) already implements [`Uint8Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array).

Comment: Wow, this is great! I had no idea about typed arrays. Thanks!

Comment: @MarkRobson by the way, `Buffer` already implements `Uint8Array` so you shouldn't even need to create `bytes`. You can just call `return Array.prototype.map.call(buffer, ...).join('')` I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: This is great! Thanks @PatrickRoberts ! If you're interested, I'm learning about Tezos so creating a library: https://github.com/roppa/tezmania. Cheers!